# converting a node.js project into a wp plugin

Tags: node.js, wordpress

What is the best way to take code written in node.js and convert it to a WP plug in without re-writing everything? Anyone have experience in doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this way could solve the problem:

Using browserify library for building `bundle.js` file of your plugin.

Then you could use `wp_enqueue_sript` function with `wp_enqueue_scripts` action function to include only your bundle.js.

Browserify library:
https://github.com/browserify/browserify

Script for building main plugin script `bundle.js`

```
browserify main.js > bundle.js
```

You only need to build your script and create basic plugin dir,
f.e if your plugin name is My Awesome Plugin,

You need to create `wp-content/my-awesome-plugin/my-awesome-plugin.php`

And place your package.json and your js code to `wp-content/my-awesome-plugin`

catalog.

Then, the content of the `my-awesome-plugin.php` file could have only including `bundle.js` file

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: My Awesome Plugin
Text Domain: my-awesome-plugin
*/

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
        wp_enqueue_script(
            'my-awesome-plugin',
            plugins_url( 'bundle.js', __FILE__ ),
            [],
            1,
            true
        );
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks will have to give it a shot. Will let you know if it works